# The nuget command failed with exit code(1) The element <ProductVersion> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized

Tags: build, azure-devops, ssas, azure-pipelines

I'm setting a build in Azure DevOps Pipelines, I have in repos some solutions including a SQL Server Analysis Project. This project triggers a error in the build for the NuGetCommand:

```
[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) ...: error MSB4067: The element <ProductVersion> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized.)
[error]Packages failed to restore
[section]Finishing: NuGetCommand
```

Any ideas how to solve this error? Maybe run the NuGetCommand for all projects except this SSAS, how can I exclude this solution/project?

I tried to Manage NuGet Packages for this SQL Server Analysis Project, but is not supported.

I have this code in the azure pipeline, I need to run this command for every solutions except SQL Server Analysis Project.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

Comment: Hi, just want to know does Leo's answer could help you solve the error? You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it indeed help. But if you still facing any other issue, feel free to leave comment there:-)

Answer (score 3):

> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) The element  beneath element  is unrecognized

This issue is more related to the MSBuild instead of nuget.

Since [NuGet is now fully integrated into MSBuild](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-now-fully-integrated-into-msbuild/), when we invoke nuget to restore packages, it will call MSBuild auto-detection. There is a [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/2064) in MSBuild 15 about it.

Besides,

> the latest version of Microsoft Reporting Services Projects for Visual
>   Studio (1.18) adds MSBuild support for SSRS projects. With this
>   installed, SSRS projects can be updated to a format supported by
>   MSBuild, which prevents this problem from happening.

So, to resolve this issue, please update your Visual Studio on the agent server to the latest version to check if you still have this issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Updating Visual Studio did resolve my issue. Thanks!